# Python TKINTER Text Input

Tags: python, tkinter, textinput

I am fairly new to Python and I am encountering an error with Tkinter text boxes. I can't get one to appear in my window. My program doesn't work now because of this.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnCFx.png)

I get a button to appear but I do not have a text box appearing. This is for a very simple password guesser for a project I'm working on. You type in a number and it tries to guess what number you typed in. I tested with a lot of different online resources and copied code from Google and I either got the same result or my window didn't appear at all.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: There's nothing in your code that creates a text box.

Comment: Use `Entry()` to create a text entry box. See https://python-course.eu/tkinter/entry-widgets-in-tkinter.php

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get some user input in tkinter and compare it to a generated variable, here is an approach for that, I hope this helps you out:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Entry, Label
import random

root = Tk()

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack()


def click():
    user_input = e1.get()
    # Generate your random password (using a number for simplicity)
    a = random.randrange(1, 10)
    if int(user_input) == a:
        l1 = Label(root, text="You guessed the password")
        l1.pack()


b1 = Button(root, text="Check password", command=click)
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you have any further questions, please let me know.